# values are not being saved to backend database

Tags: odoo

When trying to save certain values, from either the web interface or from a Python script using the XMLRPC interface, those values are not written to the database backend (postgresql in this case).

I have double-checked that the values are getting to the module-table code, and even to the openerp orm, but not to postgres.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to check for:

- field is not `read-only` in `..._view.xml` file (not the problem, though, if the data is getting to the module-table code, as in this case)
- field is not `read-only` in the `.py` file
- another module/table has not redefined the field as a function field with no `fnct_inv` setting

Comment: so did you find the problem

Comment: @Cherif:  At various times it's been any of the three listed.  In the case that got me to write this question/answer, it was the third.